# CUDA: How can one extract specific image points into a continuous vector?

Tags: arrays, image, image-processing, cuda

I want to write a CUDA function that extracts image points which meet a certain condition, and then place them in a contiguous block of memory on the device.

The reason for the points being in a contiguous block of memory on the device is so that I can then immediately process these points in parallel using block and thread IDs as indexes for points in this list.

If I process the points using the same kernel (function) used to detect them, I am wasting a majority of my threads since I want to assign one thread per image point and very few threads will belong to desired points. The rest of the threads will just have to sit and wait. Not to mention that the threads which are processing the desired points will belong to different blocks, severely undermining the intended gain from parallelizing the operation in the first place.

If you have any suggestions on how I can take a set of points, and transfer them to a new location on the device in parallel(!), I'm open to ideas. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a common way to do this:

- Kernel 1: Extract the image points and write them to an array. The result in the array is non-contiguous.
- Gather the points in the non-contiguous array into a contiguous array.
- Kernel 2: Work on the image points.

Kernel 1 might have written the image points into an array that has gaps, since you cannot predict how many image points will result. So, you need to **gather** the written image points together before you run Kernel 2 on it. The gathering is pretty easy to do using if you use a library like **Thrust**. For example, its [**remove_if**](http://thrust.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.0/doc/html/group__stream__compaction.html) function can be used to remove the points which are marked invalid or empty.

Answer (score 0):

you could also try add the results directly into the output vector using atomic functions, i.e.:

```
__global__ void kernel( dataType *inputImage, dataType *a, int *sizeof_A)
{
    // map from threadIdx/BlockIdx to pixel position
    int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    int offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

    if (inputImage[offset] == /* your condition */ ) {
        int arrayLastPosition = atomicAdd(sizeof_A, 1);
        a[arrayLastPosition] = /* your mark */;
    }
}
```

You will have in sizeof_A the length of the array at the end of this kernel. This is a naive approach but could be interesting compare it with the intermediate step of gather the elements to move them at the beginning of the array.

Comment: For anything other than cases with extremely sparse output, atomic memory access will be much, much slower than running a separate stream compaction kernel over the output.

Comment: Also atomic in shared memory?